# Spritekit parallel scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit

I have an issue with parallel scrolling with an object on my game , my object is a line that should be repeated , but my code scrolls the line out of screen and then it returns to the first position and scroll again :

```
 - (void)bricksEdgeAnimation {

    SKSpriteNode *bEdge = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"edge.png"];
    bEdge.position = self.view.center;
    bEdge.name = @"edge";
    [self addChild:bEdge];


}

- (void)moveBg
{
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"edge" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)
     {
         SKSpriteNode * bg = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
         bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x , bg.position.y - SPEED);

         if (bg.position.y <= -bg.size.width)
         {
             bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x ,
                                       bg.position.y + bg.size.width*2);
         }
     }];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

    if (_lastUpdateTime)
    {
        _dt = currentTime - _lastUpdateTime;
    }
    else
    {
        _dt = 0;
    }

    _lastUpdateTime = currentTime;

    [self moveBg];

}
```

it should be like this :

[image] [image]

how should change my code to repeat this line after each other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a second "edge" node:

```
- (void)bricksEdgeAnimation {

    SKSpriteNode *bEdge = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"edge.png"];
    bEdge.position = self.view.center;
    bEdge.name = @"edge";
    [self addChild:bEdge];

    //2nd node - note the name is the same
    SKSpriteNode *bEdge1 = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"edge.png"];
    bEdge1.position = CGPointMake(bEdge.position.x,bEdge.position.y+(bEdge.size.height));
    bEdge1.name = @"edge";
    [self addChild:bEdge1];
}

//note I changed "width" to "height"
- (void)moveBg
{
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"edge" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop)
     {
         SKSpriteNode * bg = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
         bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x , bg.position.y - SPEED);

         if (bg.position.y <= -bg.size.width)
         {
             bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x ,
                                       bg.position.y + bg.size.height*2);
         }
     }];
}
```